# Objective-c: How to cast to a class type by name

Tags: objective-c

I try to do something like this:

```
Class CustomClass = [MyClass class];

// _object is an instance variable typed with "id"
CustomClass *obj =  CustomClass *_object;         // Error here
```

Is it possible to cast an object to a class by name in Objective-C?

#### Updates

I'm actually writing a getter

```
- (id)photoFrame
{
    if (NSClassFromString(@"CustomClass")) {

        return (CustomClass1 *) _object;
    } else {
        return (CustomClass2 *) _object;
    }
}
```

The error message is `Expected expression`.

Comment: Why??  What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Where in the code is it saying "Expected expression"? In the `if (NSClassFromString(@"CustomClass"))` part?

Comment: Also there's no point in doing `return (CustomClass1 *) _object;` unless you're either going to return something of another type (i.e not type `id`) or actually use something from `CustomClass1` before you return it. I think most of us are confused on what this is supposed to do.

Comment: You don't need to cast to or from `id` anyway, it'll convert implicitly.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. Casting an Objective-C object doesn't do any meaningful work. I've written a small library though that may help encourage the kind of type checking you're looking for. https://github.com/fcanas/SafeCast

Answer (score 0):

CustomClass *obj =  (CustomClass *)_object;